# how to find out the timezone of given time from mysql db in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, timezone

I am quite new to Node js.
I want to know what timezone the given datetime value, which comes from mysql db, it is .

For example

```
    const conference = await mysqlHelper.query(conferenceSql);
    // select query
    const time = conference[0].created_datetime
    // I wonder how to get the timezone from this time variable here.
    console.log(time) 
    // console.log returns '2021-02-23T01:30:00.000Z' to the terminal
```

mysql value type: datetime
I know I could directly look up the db table instead of figuring out in node js. However, this is a required task for validation in my server.
Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Is it a `datetime` in the database or a `timestamp`?

Comment: Hi. `datetime` :)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql `datetime` does not store time zone information.

`2021-02-23T01:30:00.000Z` is displayed in an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, being in UTC.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that '000Z' thing represents timezone ! thanks so much !

Comment: The `000` are milliseconds, only the `Z` is the UTC timezone.